# What is the difference between SKScene.size.width SKSpriteNode.size.width?

Tags: ios, swift, game-development

I'm new to **swift 5**.
I printed out the `self.size.width` in `GameScene` and the result is **677.0**
I printed out the `self.size.width` from another class - lets say `Ground` and the result is **4002.0**

I'm confused, please help.

Thanks a lot.

**GameScene.swift:**

import SpriteKit

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    let cam = SKCameraNode()
    let bee = SKSpriteNode()
    let ground = Ground()

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
      self.anchorPoint = .zero
      //self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.4, green: 0.6, blue: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
      self.camera = cam
      self.addingTheFlyingBee()
      self.addBackground()

      let bee2 = Bee()
      bee2.position = CGPoint(x: 325, y: 325)
      self.addChild(bee2)

      let bee3 = Bee()
      bee3.position = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 325)
      self.addChild(bee3)

      ground.position = CGPoint(x: -self.size.width * 2, y: 0)
      ground.size = CGSize(width: self.size.width * 6, height: 0)
      ground.createChildren()
      self.addChild(ground)
  }

    override func didSimulatePhysics() {
        self.camera!.position = bee.position
  }

    func addBackground() {
      let bg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background-menu")
      bg.position = CGPoint(x: 220, y: 220)
      bg.zPosition = -1
      self.addChild(bg)

  }

    func addingTheFlyingBee() {
        bee.position = CGPoint(x: 250, y: 250)
        bee.size = CGSize(width: 38, height: 34)
        self.addChild(bee)

        let beeAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Enemies")
        let beeFrames : [SKTexture] = [
            beeAtlas.textureNamed("bee"),
            beeAtlas.textureNamed("bee-fly")
        ]
        let flyAction = SKAction.animate(with: beeFrames, timePerFrame: 0.14)
        let beeAction = SKAction.repeatForever(flyAction)
        bee.run(beeAction)

        let pathLeft = SKAction.moveBy(x: -200, y: -10, duration: 2)
        let pathRight = SKAction.moveBy(x: 200, y: 10, duration: 2)
        let flipTextureNegative = SKAction.scaleX(to: -1, duration: 0)
        let flipTexturePositive = SKAction.scaleX(to: 1, duration: 0)
        let flightOfTheBee = SKAction.sequence([ pathLeft, flipTextureNegative, pathRight, flipTexturePositive])
        let neverEndingFlight = SKAction.repeatForever(flightOfTheBee)
        bee.run(neverEndingFlight)

    }
```

**Ground.swift:**

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class Ground: SKSpriteNode, GameSprite {
  var textureAtlas: SKTextureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Environment")
  var initialSize = CGSize.zero

  func createChildren() {
    self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
    let texture = textureAtlas.textureNamed("ground")
    var tileCount: CGFloat = 0
    let tileSize = CGSize(width: 35, height: 300)

    while tileCount * tileSize.width < self.size.width {
      let tileNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)
      tileNode.size = tileSize
      tileNode.position.x = tileCount * tileSize.width
      tileNode.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
      self.addChild(tileNode)
      tileCount += 1
    }

  }

  func onTap() {}
}
```

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve]. Without knowing the types declared in `Ground.swift` and `gameScene.swift` no one will be able to tell you what `size` might represent for each of them.

Comment: I've added the both of the file's code

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the question. Since your scene width is 677.0px and your ground
width should be 6 * scene width so 4062px. 
Is your question "Why is ground node width 4002px instead of 4062px?" or "What is the difference between those properties?"

If you question is the second one then this should be an answer:
`SKScene.size.width` will return width of the current scene while `SKSpriteNode.size.width` will return width of the target node in your case "ground" node.

`self.size.width` will return width of the current class you're editing.

So in GameScene.swift file if you call `self.size.width` inside a `class GameScene: SKScene` it will return GameScene width.

In Ground.swift file calling `self.size.width` inside a `class Ground: SKSpriteNode, GameSprite` will return Ground width.

I hope this answers your question.